# out of memory java heap size

Tags: java, sockets, nio

http://www.coderpanda.com/java-socket-programming-transferring-large-sized-files-through-socket/

The code in the above link is working but upto a certain amount of data can be transferred. when i tried to transfer a movie of format .mkv of size approx 334 MB it gives me error of "out of Memory, java heap size". I am a begginner and i dont know how to solve this i tried to increase the buffersize in client side program but the problem still persist. please help me.

Comment: Try **reducing** the buffer size or increasing the JVM heap.

Comment: I can't fail to notice that the code is too complicated for what it does. There is no real need to copy the read buffers and the background thread is also useless. The server should start one background per connection instead.

Comment: Transferring large files should be done by acquiring a [*channel* for the socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getChannel()) and a [channel for the file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...)) instead of streams and a call to [`targetFileChannel.transferFrom(sourceSocketChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel,%20long,%20long)) for the entire transfer.

Comment: thanks :) and Sir Holger, may you please give me an example of how to use targetfilechannel etc.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is this line:

```
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024 * 100000];
```

That is allocating a buffer of ~100 Mbytes ... which ridiculously large.

Either reduce it (by a factor of 10 or 100), or run your application with a larger heap.

<sup>(@Aaron Digulla and @Holger's comments above are also apropos.  This is really not what one would call "high quality" code ...)</sup>

Comment: +1 but I would reduce it by a factor of around 10,000. Considering there is also a socket send buffer in the kernel, the benefits of application buffering are asymptotically zero once you get beyond quite a small number of K.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at the JVM memory parameters. You need to increase the JVM heap size not the buffer size. check this parameters

```
-Xmx2048m -> this param to set the max memory that the JVM can allocate
-Xms1024m -> the init memory that JVM will allocate on the start up
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -> this for the max Permanent Generation memory
-XX:MaxNewSize=  -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
-XX:NewSize=614m -> this need to be 40% from your Xmx value
```

Answer (score 0):

try using jdk 5.0 or above.
in jdk 4.0 the initial heap size was 64 MB.JDK 7.0 u9 or above will be much better.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the code in that link is complete rubbish. It isn't necessary to use enormous buffers and it certainly isn't necessary to use System.arraycopy() when copying streams. Any reasonable buffer size will do. This won't be hundreds of megabytes, it will be measured in kilobytes.

The canonical way to copy a stream in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

This works for any buffer size greater than zero. Note that there is no System.arraycopy() and no allocation of new byte arrays during the copy, so it can't possibly run out of memory. Note also that it is *considerably* simpler than the code in your link.

Your question is tagged NIO but the code in the link uses streams, so I've given you a streams-based answer.

Comment: OK thanks Sir. And Sir, it would be wonderful if you would give me a link to learn about NIO transfer

Comment: I see no reason to bother with NIO for this simple task.